# Form not responding using submit codeignitor for SQL INSERT

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to working with codeignitor and i have been stuck on this problem for some time. I can't seem to find the answer i am looking for, or i am to unexperienced to find it. Anyhow - I am trying to create a form that inserts data into my sql database, form is not delivering any type of error but nothing happens in the database, what am i missing?

the check error code is not even responding:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die;
```

My Controller (Blog_add.php):

```
<?php

class blog_add extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct();

}
function index() {

    $this->load->model('blog_add_model');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostbildPathInput', 'Bild', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[100]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostdateDayInput', 'Dag', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostdateMonthInput', 'M&aring;nad', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[20]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostdateArInput', '&Aring;r', 'required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostcategoryInput', 'Kategori', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[35]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostRubrikInput', 'Rubrik', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[100]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpostbeskrivningInput', 'Beskrivning', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[200]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpoststyckeEttInput', 'Blogparagraph 1', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[400]');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('blogpoststyckeTvaInput', 'Blogparagraph 2', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[400]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('auth/blog_create');
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'blogpostbildPath' => $this->input->post('blogpostbildPathInput'),
            'blogpostdateDay' => $this->input->post('blogpostdateDayInput'),
            'blogpostdateMonth' => $this->input->post('blogpostdateMonthInput'),
            'blogpostdateAr' => $this->input->post('blogpostdateArInput'),
            'blogpostcategory' => $this->input->post('blogpostcategoryInput'),
            'blogpostRubrik' => $this->input->post('blogpostRubrikInput'),
            'blogpostbeskrivning' => $this->input->post('blogpostbeskrivningInput'),
            'blogpoststyckeEtt' => $this->input->post('blogpoststyckeEttInput'),
            'blogpoststyckeTva' => $this->input->post('blogpoststyckeTvaInput'),
        );

    // echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die;
    // is not working here

        $this->insert_model->form_insert($data); 
        $data['message'] = 'Data Inserted Successfully';
        $this->load->view('auth/blog_create', $data);
        }
    }  
}

?>
```

My Model (Blog_add_model.php):

```
<?php
class blog_add_model extends CI_Model{
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}
function form_insert($data){
$pagaendeDb = $this->load->database('blog');
$this->$pagaendeDb->insert('projekt', $data);
}
}
?>
```

My View: (blog_create.php):

```
<?php
include('phpTemplates/head.php');
include('phpTemplates/header.php');
?>

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <h2>Lägg till nytt blogginlägg</h2>
    <div class="row" style="background: #fbf9ff; padding-top: 22px; margin-bottom: 60px; box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)">

        <div class="col-lg-12">

            <?php echo form_open('Blog_add'); ?>

            <?php if (isset($message)) { ?>
            <CENTER>
                <h3 style="color:green;">Data inserted successfully</h3>
            </CENTER>
            <?php } ?>

            <div class="col-20">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 14px">
                    <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'blogpostbildPath', 'name' => 'blogpostbildPathInput', 'type' => 'file')); ?>
                    <?php

                        $dayOptions = array('Dag');

                        for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) {
                            $inputValue  = (string) $i;
                            $dayOptions[$i] = $inputValue;
                            $dayOptions[$i][0] = $inputValue;
                        }

                        echo form_dropdown('blogpostdateDayInput', $dayOptions, '');
                    ?>

                    <?php 

                        $monthOptions = array(
                            'Månad' => 'Månad',
                            'Jan'  => 'Januari',
                            'Feb'    => 'Februari',
                            'Mar'   => 'Mars',
                            'Apr' => 'April',
                            'Maj'  => 'Maj',
                            'Jun'    => 'Juni',
                            'Jul'   => 'Juli',
                            'Aug' => 'Augusti',
                            'Sep'  => 'September',
                            'Okt'    => 'Oktober',
                            'Nov'   => 'November',
                            'Dec' => 'December'
                        );

                        echo form_dropdown('blogpostdateMonthInput', $monthOptions, '');
                    ?>

                    <?php 

                        $yearOptions = array(
                            'År' => 'År',
                            '2016'  => '2016',
                            '2017'    => '2017',
                            '2018'   => '2018',
                            '2019' => '2019',
                            '2020' => '2020',
                            '2021' => '2021'
                        );

                        echo form_dropdown('blogpostdateArInput', $yearOptions, '');
                    ?>


                    <?php 

                        $statusOptions = array(
                            'Status' => 'Status',
                            'Pågående'  => 'Pågående',
                            'Avslutade'    => 'Avslutade',
                            'Övrigt' => 'Övrigt'
                        );

                        echo form_dropdown('blogpostStatusInput', $statusOptions, '');
                    ?>


                    <?php 

                        $categoryOptions = array(
                            'Kategori' => 'Kategori',
                            'Nybyggt'  => 'Nybyggt',
                            'Stambyte'    => 'Stambyte',
                            'Renovering'   => 'Renovering',
                            'Övrigt' => 'Övrigt',
                        );

                        echo form_dropdown('blogpostcategoryInput', $categoryOptions, '');
                    ?>


                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">

                <?php echo form_error('blogpostRubrik'); ?><br />
                <?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'blogpostRubrik', 'name' => 'blogpostRubrikInput', 'value' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Rubrik på inlägg', 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control w-100')); ?><br />

            </div>

            <div class="col-6">

                <?php echo form_error('blogpostbeskrivning'); ?><br />
                <?php echo form_textarea(array('id' => 'blogpostbeskrivning', 'name' => 'blogpostbeskrivningInput', 'value' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Beskrivning av inlägg', 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '3', 'class' => 'form-control w-100', 'style' => 'height: 128px;')); ?><br />

            </div>

            <div class="col-10">

                <?php echo form_error('blogpoststyckeEtt'); ?><br />
                <?php echo form_textarea(array('id' => 'blogpoststyckeEtt', 'name' => 'blogpoststyckeEttInput', 'value' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Blogginlägg stycke 1', 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '9', 'class' => 'form-control w-100', 'style' => 'height: 252px;')); ?><br />

            </div>

            <div class="col-10">

                <?php echo form_error('blogpoststyckeTva'); ?><br />
                <?php echo form_textarea(array('id' => 'blogpoststyckeTva', 'name' => 'blogpoststyckeTvaInput', 'value' => '', 'placeholder' => 'Blogginlägg stycke 2', 'class' => 'form-control w-100', 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '9', 'style' => 'height: 252px;')); ?><br />

            </div>

            <div class="col-12">

                <?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Lägg till', 'class' => 'button button-contactForm btn_1')); ?>
            </div>


            <?php echo form_close(); ?><br />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
include('phpBodyTemplates/importJs.php');
include('phpTemplates/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: you should not update your original question with code you get from the answers, as this destroys the original post and makes it impossible for further readers to follow up. I've rolled back your updates. You can obviously add an edit, which doesn't change the code

Comment: Ah, thanks for telling me that - i am new to stack overflow, will definatly remember this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model loaded on the controller is different. Here you load `$this->load->model('blog_add_model');`. Keep your `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` from `config.php`, So it errors in `logs` or keep `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` in `index.php` while development

replace

```
$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);
```

with

```
 $this->blog_add_model->form_insert($data);
```

in controller

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply mate! I have changed the model but still not working, log_threshold is changed. I am working on this project on my own site so there are no visitors, is there any specific reason to have development environment?

Comment: development environment keep you updated with errors and warnings

Comment: print last query after insert query with `echo $this->db->last_query();` and try to figure it out while data not inserting

Comment: also try with an update in model. replace `$this->$pagaendeDb->insert('projekt', $data);` with `$this->db->insert('projekt', $data);`

Comment: Reason i use $this->$pagaendeDb->insert('projekt', $data); is because i use 2 different databases, so if i us db instead of $pagaendeDb i am in the users database - i want to separate the blog and users, is this bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling the correct model.

instead of `$this->insert_model->form_insert($data);` you need to call Blog_add_model (the one you have loaded in your controller with `$this->load->model('blog_add_model');`

like this:

`$this->Blog_add_model->form_insert($data);`

you can always debug your code and see if $data has arrived at a certain point in controller or model, checking what it contains with `echo '<pre>';print_r($data); die;`

Comment: Thanks Vickel, I have updated this and trying to detect how it is all wokring with what the $data variable contains, but it does not seem to answer me, you see the reason?

Answer (score 0):

1) First thing is use Case sensitive for controller and model class.
2) Make sure the form action url pointing to your controller action(blog_add).
3) Check the post data on controller after submit the form from view template.
    print_f($this->input->post());
Ensure the post data printing or not on the controller action. then you can move to form validation and insert data to database

Comment: Thanks Govind for your response. Are you refering to capitalization of the names of controllers and models? I have the first letter capitalized, however the class inside is not capitalized, but refering to the model inside controllers i use capitalized first letters, this is as i've understood it from codeigniters documentation, is this correct?

Comment: Please refer these code. Maybe help to you. They followed the clean and simple code to insert data in table :https://www.phptpoint.com/codeigniter-insert-data-database/